# How do I see what's in the run queue on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, queue, sar

The load on my server is very high, even though there doesn't seem to be much disk activity and the CPU is idle. Using sar, I can see the run queue is getting full, but is there any way to see what's in the run queue?

Comment: What do you mean by "the load on my server is very high" and "the CPU is idle"?  Load average should correspond somewhat to CPU load.

Comment: @mpez0 In Linux, load average is deceptive. It is measuring what's in the run queue, not the CPU load. This is important to know. It means uninterruptible disk IO could cause a high load average although the CPU is idle.

Comment: @billyw You did see the "somewhat" in my comment, right?

Answer (score 4):

Start with top.  It should list all or most of the run queue in the first page.  Also 'ps r -A' will list all processes in the run queue.

Answer (score -1):

```
ps –ef
```

shows every (-e) running process in a full (-f) detailed list